# Why if(nil) is evaluated as true?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to check if a key exists in NSDictionary, and then handles the case. But why is this case being satisfied, when the value is nil?

```
results: NSDictionary
println(results)
```

prints this:

```
{
    error = (
        {
            code = 402;
            message = "User exists for this email";
            username = "xyz@gmail.com";
        }
    );
}
```

but when I check in a if block, why is is getting inside?

```
    if(results["results"])
    {
      println("why here?");
    }
```

Here if(nil) should fail, but its not.
I also tried to use, results.valueForKey("results"), results.objectForKey("results"), but all of them give exceptions.

If I use this it crashes with run-time error:

```
if let dict: results["results"]
```

**Update**:
Just found that that the control jumps to the beginning of the function after first time is evaluated correctly, and then the run-time occurs. So why the function loops twice and then crashes?

Comment: try `if let dict = results["results"]`

Comment: tried that, still crashes.

Comment: Crashes? That's a compiler bug, file a radar.

Comment: In your question you said the program enters the `if` statement. Does it do that or does it crash?

Comment: yeah it crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION which is very strange. as it should be straightforward, to check for if key exists this way.

Comment: @IsaacDrachman just updated the question

Comment: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION is normally an indication of an assertion failure in a library function—assertion failures deliberately throw a bad instruction at the CPU to trip it up.

Comment: Works fine here in a playground and in an app. Are you using  Xcode6-Beta2?

Comment: This problem was occurring because of wrong way of parsing the JSON into NSArray & NSDictionary. And as it happens at run-time, the xcode beta version was crashing.

Answer (score 3):

That is not the behaviour I'm seeing. The following code prints `"just what I expect"`, as expected.

```
let results: NSDictionary = ["foo": "bar"]

if results["baz"] {
    println("why here?");
} else {
    println("just what I expect");
}
```

There must be something else to it that isn't covered in your question.

Comment: I have the NSDictionary printed in the question above. Can't understand why its not working here.

Comment: I just tried this same code and it crashed on the if(results["baz"]) line, with this exception: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0).

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying this in a playground:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var results = ["foo": "fooVar", "bar": "barVar"]
// ["foo": "fooVar", "bar": "barVar"]

results["foo"]
// {Some "fooVar"}

results["baz"] == nil
// true

if results["baz"]
{
    "hi"
    // not shown
}
else
{
    "seems to be working"
    //shown. 
}
```

So there has to be something somewhere else in your program that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Undo has mentioned in the answer above, it indeed was a problem in the later part of the function, and was throwing an exception with incorrect way the JSON data was being parsed as NSDictionary. But instead of showing where exactly the exception was occurring, xcode tries to trace back up the function and shows the exception at exit point of the function.

Fixing the JSON parsing, removed the error. Its better to write proper error handlers to avoid this kind of problems.